# How to diable logging to console (pig embedded in python)

Tags: python, embed, jython, apache-pig

I am currently playing with embedding pig into python, and whenever I run the file it works, however it cloggs up the command line with output like the following:

```
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/hue-plugins-2.3.0-cdh4.3.0.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar'
```

Command line input:

```
pig embedded_pig_testing.py -p /home/cloudera/Documents/python_testing_config_files/test002_config.cfg
```

the parameter passed is a file that contains a bunch of variables I am using in the test.

Is there any way to get the script to not log these actions to the command line?

Answer (score 1):

Logging in Java programs/libraries is usually configured by means of a configuration or `.properties` file. I'm sure there's one for Pig. Something that might be what you're looking for is http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pig/trunk/conf/pig.properties.

**EDIT:** looks like this is specific to Jython.

I have not been able to determine if it's possible at all to disable this, but unless I could find something cleaner, I'd consider simply redirecting `sys.stderr` (or `sys.stdout`) during the `.jar` loading phase:

```
import os
import sys

old_stdout, old_stderr = sys.stdout, sys.stderr
sys.stdout = sys.stderr = open(os.devnull, 'w')

do_init()  # load your .jar's here

sys.stdout, sys.stderr = old_stdout, old_stderr
```

Comment: I have run exactly the same pig code on its own (without python embedding) and it doesn't output the logs I specified. I have already configured my pig properties to avoid those logs. I'm fairly sure that the ones I am getting are due to the python code.

Comment: This seems to eliminate some of the logged error messages, however it does not disable all of them. Upon looking at the remaining output, I think the problem might be that some jars are loaded automatically without me specifically calling them due to how I envoke the script. I'll add some more information to the question to hopefuly give you a better idea of what I am doing.

Comment: I have to admit, I'm not really familiar with Jython, just Python in general.

Answer (score 0):

This logging comes from jython scanning your Java packages to build a cache for later use: https://wiki.python.org/jython/PackageScanning

So long as your script only uses full class imports (no `import x.y.*` wildcards), you can disable package scanning via the `python.cachedir.skip` property:

```
pig ... -Dpython.cachedir.skip=true  ...
```

Frustratingly, I believe jython writes these messages to stdout instead of stderr, so piping stderr elsewhere won't help you out.

Another option is to use streaming python instead of jython whenever pig 0.12 ships.  See [PIG-2417](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-2417) for more details on that.

Comment: tried the following command line `pig -Dpython.cachedir.skip=true basic_xml_reader.py -p /home/cloudera/Documents/python_testing_config_files/test002_config.cfg`. While the program still ran fine, it did not stop the logged messages from filling the screen. Any idea what I am doing wrong?